# Как отобразить ListView во всю длину?

Tags: android, listview, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть страница с разметкой, корнейвой элемент `ScrollView`, в конце этой страницы располагается `ListView`, задача: отобразить все элементы списка с возможностью прокрутки  `ScrollView` же).
У меня получается показать либо один элемент списка, с прокруткой, по одному элементу, либо задать фиксированный размер в dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая [ссылка](http://akuma.su/blog/listview-inside-scrollview.html), выдаваемая гуглом по запросу

> listview in scrollview android

ведёт на статью на великом и могучем, автор коей ссылается на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Суть статьи - нужно вычислить суммарную высоту всех элементов ListView и задать полученную высоту самому ListView:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
if (listAdapter == null)
    return;

int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int totalHeight = 0;
View view = null;
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
    if (i == 0)
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Вызывать метод надо после инициализации и наполнения списка элементами.

Чуть подробнее - по ссылке в начале ответа.

P.S. По всему Интернету говорят, что это плохой подход, но раз надо... Лично я в этой ситуации просто вручную в коде добавляю нужное кол-во элементов в конец дочернего элемента ScrollView. И верю, что это правильнее и выигрышнее в смысле производительности.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось, только нужно еще немного подогнать под разметку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб единственный косяк, если размер лист итема изменяется, то высота неправильная будет

Comment: @Garf1eld, это да, поэтому я проголосовал за ответ @gcoder. Его ответ кажется мне более подходящим.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы на вашем место попробовал то, что вы пихаете в scrollview, сделать, как header в listview.
То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, не оч. хороший подход, хотя бы потому, что в android существует ограничение на количество view в разметке, и если данных в listview много, то даже если вы не упретесь в это ограничение, создание этого огромного количества view будет довольно трудозатратной операцией.

Comment: И какой ограничение? В общем, не такая уже и редкая эта задача, у меня часто попадается задание - вывести 4-6 однотипных пунктов во всю длину, и если бы был удобный способ держать развернутый список - я бы использовал его, а так или хардкод высоты списка или просто тексьюхи в леяут.

Comment: Ну, listview не зря инфлайтит только то количество view, которые помещаются по высоте. Экономия памати + процессора/батареи.

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую!
Может быть, стоит попробовать в ScrollView вставить LinearLayout  и в LinearLayout вставить ваш список, при этом выставить параметры, которые вам необходимы, ширина и т.д.
Должно получиться, так же не забывайте выставить для LinearLayout, orientation.